# how can I replace elements in a pandas column by a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe column to store hashtags, each row of this column is a list of strings like this:

```
df.hashtag

0        [#MondayMotivation, #BlackMamba, #RIPMamba, #c...
1        [#Periscope, #HeartGang, #SpreadLuv, #KobeRIP,...
2        [#Periscope, #HeartGang, #SpreadLuv, #KobeRIP,...
3        [#RoomOfMystery, #BuenLunes, #GRAMMYs, #27Ene,...
4        [#Periscope, #HeartGang, #SpreadLuv, #KobeRIP,...
5        [#Periscope, #HeartGang, #SpreadLuv, #KobeRIP,...
```

I mean, each line of df.hashtag is a list like this:

```
df.hashtag[0]

['#MondayMotivation',
 '#BlackMamba',
 '#RIPMamba',
 '#coronavirus',
 '#love',
 '#Califórnia']
```

As you can see, there are many similar hashtags representing the same meanings, for instance, `#COV_19`

and `#COVID_19`, so I want to replace these elements into the same string `#COVID19`

so I created a list of these hashtags not in the right format. Like this:

```
token = ['#Covid_19',
 '#covid2019',
 '#covid19',
 '#covid_19',
 '#COVid',
 '#COVID__19']
```

Then I tried the replace method but failed.

```
df.replace(token,'#COVID-19',inplace=True)
```

how can I replace these hashtags into the string that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following. Add similar lines if you have more elements to be replaced.

```
token = ['#Covid_19',
 '#covid2019',
 '#covid19',
 '#covid_19',
 '#COVid',
 '#COVID__19']

l=list(df.hashtag)
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i]=['#COVID19' if x in token else x for x in l[i]]

df.hashtag=l
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, First [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) then create a dict of token as key & `"#COVID_19"` as value to [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace) finally `groupby` to get original back.

```
(df.hashtag.explode().replace({t : "#COVID_19" for t in token})
        .groupby(level=0).apply(list))
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: What is the version of pandas your using, explode was introduced in version 0.25

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```
for t in token:
    df['hashtag'] = df['hashtag'].str.replace(t, '#COVID19')
```

Another suggestion would be, for such instances of your token list, you might want to clean up your data such as capitalizing all the hashtag, remove special characters and replace year to a fixed format. That way your token list is smaller and your loops are shorter.